# How to create main class for public static int method in java?

Tags: java

I'm sorry for this noob question but I'm not really familiar with this method. This method generates check digit for ean 8 barcodes. How can I create the main class for this method? Are there any other ways of generating check digit for ean 8 barcodes?

```
public class CheckDigit { 
   public static int checkdigit(String idWithoutCheckdigit) {
      String validChars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVYWXZ_";
      idWithoutCheckdigit = idWithoutCheckdigit.trim().toUpperCase();
      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < idWithoutCheckdigit.length(); i++) {
         char ch = idWithoutCheckdigit.charAt(idWithoutCheckdigit.length() - i - 1);


         if (validChars.indexOf(ch) == -1)
            throw new RuntimeException("\"" + ch + "\" is an invalid character");

         int digit = ch - 48;
         int weight;

         if (i % 2 == 0) {
            weight = (2 * digit) - (digit / 5) * 9;
         } else {
            weight = digit;
         }
         sum += weight;
      }

      sum = Math.abs(sum) + 10;
      return (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;

   }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(String... args) { System.out.println(checkDigit("mystring")); }`

Answer (score 0):

Just add another method in your class:

```
public class CheckDigit {
    public static int checkdigit(String idWithoutCheckdigit) {
        /*
            Good looking implementation of your method
        */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //fill the String with a expected value
        String idWithoutCheckdigit = "...";
        //evaluate the String with your method
        int useAGoodNameForThisVar = checkdigit(idWithoutCheckdigit);
        //print the results
        System.out.println("checkdigit(" + idWithoutCheckdigit + ") = " + useAGoodNameForThisVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry sir. I'm a newbie. What is the meaning of the "expected value" stated on the comment below the public static void main? Thanks!

Comment: @jedcute29 it means that you should put the value that you will give to `String idWithoutCheckdigit` to test if your `checkdigit` method works (or not).

Comment: So does it mean that i will give 7 random numbers, sir? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jedcute29 yes, it could be `String idWithoutCheckdigit = "1234567";` or `String idWithoutCheckdigit = "7654321";`, this depends on your needs to test the method.

Answer (score 0):

Main methods in java look like this (having a main method makes a class the main class).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     //code...
}
```

Perhaps then you want to then call your method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     // print the results of your method
     System.out.println(checkdigit("This is the string i'm giving to my method."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class CheckDigit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            for (String arg : args) {
                System.out.println(CheckDigit.checkdigit(arg));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please give some values on the command line");
        }
    }

    public static int checkdigit(String idWithoutCheckdigit) {
        String validChars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVYWXZ_";
        idWithoutCheckdigit = idWithoutCheckdigit.trim().toUpperCase();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < idWithoutCheckdigit.length(); i++) {
            char ch = idWithoutCheckdigit.charAt(idWithoutCheckdigit.length() - i - 1);
            if (validChars.indexOf(ch) == -1)
                throw new RuntimeException("\"" + ch + "\" is an invalid character");
            int digit = ch - 48;
            int weight;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                weight = (2 * digit) - (digit / 5) * 9;
            } else {
                weight = digit;
            }
            sum += weight;
        }
        sum = Math.abs(sum) + 10;
        return (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahmm, it doesn't display anything on the output. it only says "run" and that's all. What does it mean? Thanks!

Comment: You probably didn't give it any String values on the command line when you ran it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(String each : args){
        System.out.println(CheckDigit.checkdigit(each));
    }
}
```